# ActiveMQ clustered topics and fail safety from producer point of view

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I want to setup multiple JMS nodes (brokers) which have multiple topics. Recently I discovered failover feature (http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html#FailoverTransportReference-BrokersideOptionsforFailover) which allows consumers to be distributed among all the broker nodes + redirects in case if target node failed. 
I'm new to JMS and to ActiveMQ and perhaps my question would sound stupidly, but anyway:

I wonder if ActiveMQ supports distributed Topics from producer point of view so when producer publishes the message then it appears in a cluster rather than in a single cluster node (to where producer publishes it). The reason why I'm interested in this kind of feature is because I'm afraid that if this single node (where producer publishes message) fails, then producer will not be able to publish messages until this node is up again. But it would be much more reliable if producer could publish a message to a cluster (just as producer uses failover feature) and if the original topic holder node is down, then message is just redirected to other broker nodes. I've been looking for some examples and was unable to find them. Could anybody give a hint if ActiveMQ supports this kind of feature? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you combine the failover: scheme to provide client-side recovery and then use the network-of-broker on the server-side to distribute the messages to other consumers in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was thinking about this scheme and it seems good to me but there is one problem with it: what happens if node that first receives message from producer fails? If it fails then no other brokers received messages? Should one handle this case explicitly? I mean should producer (on the code level) try to send message to another node in case if initial is down? Or is there any out-of-box support for this case?

Comment: @Andrey master+slave can help with the message recovery scenarios. 99% of the time it is recommended to _not_ have any application specific message handling. There are a number of out-of-the-box options including transactions, and other settings.. it depends on your use case, volume, server environment, programming language, protocol, etc.. I suggest you consult with an expert for a week or so to walk you through everything if this is business critical data.

Comment: @Andrey if you liked the answer, could you please accept it, thanks =)

Comment: thanks very much for your effort, now scheme is full, I just need to implement it :-)